# Recursion...I'm stuck

Tags: java, recursion

This isn't homework, it's just practice. My first method to write was:

Write a static recursive method power that takes two int arguments named x and p and returns x multiplied by itself p times.

I did that, and here is the code:

```
public static int power(int x, int p)
{
    if(p==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int result = x * power(x, p - 1);
        return result;
    }       
}
```

The next problem was:

Each level in the pyramid is a square, so if there are n levels, the bottom level has n * n balls, and the total number of balls is just
(n * n) + (number of balls in a pyramid of height n - 1).

There is just one ball in a pyramid of height 1. Write a static recursive method `getPyramidCount` that takes a single int argument representing the number of levels in a pyramid, and returns the total number of balls. (Use your power method above to square numbers.)

I'm so frustrated because I have no clue as to how to write this. I know I want to make another method that includes the power method, but I'm so clueless. Can you help me out here? At this point I feel like seeing someone's code for this is the only way for me to understand.

EDIT: Didn't mean to have 2 there. It's supposed to be x! I was doing 2 to the 8th power and forgot to put in x instead of 2!

Comment: Your code does not solve the specified problem.  [3 to the power of 3 is not 8](http://ideone.com/u4FLV9)...

Comment: Your power method is wrong, as you were already told. As for the pyramid problem, perhaps you should read about it first in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) and then you can come up with an idea.

Comment: If you really want to get your feet wet practicing recursion, try to write a method which scans a directory and all its subdirectories (and all their subdirectories, etc.) for files with names starting with a particular string. That is a very easy to visualize and thus understand application of recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm reading through an upcoming lab and I'll have to use recursion with directories and files in a week or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this line :

```
int result = 2 * power(x, p - 1);
```

should be this :

```
int result = x * power(x, p - 1);
```

but about your pyramid, your code have just one input with value of n and the return value as you said is n<sup>2</sup> + pyramid(n-1);

Comment: I know that people on this site don't like others handing out code, but this is for practice. I don't turn this code in at all. Recursion seems to be a confusing concept and my professor couldn't explain it well and the textbook was confusing. Thank you for your answer, I'll have this to look back at and reference while I practice recursion.

Comment: @NewbieNick glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't multiply by `2`. It's `x` * `x` `p` times. Like,

```
public static int power(int x, int p) {
    if (p <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return x * power(x, p - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `power` method is wrong. It would calculate 2^p instead of x^p.

Change

```
int result = 2 * power(x, p - 1);
```

to

```
int result = x * power(x, p - 1);
```

Now, for the pyramid question, the recursion is : `numBalls(n) = n^2 + numBalls(n-1)`.

Therefore, the method would look like this :

```
public static int numBalls (int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return power(n,2) + numBalls(n-1);
}
```